# Invalid form in Django

Tags: django, forms

I can not find, why I am getting an invalid form ( form.is_valid returns False )
If I raise an exception with the information of the form, this is what I am getting.:

```
Exception Value:    
('valid_form: ', False, "{'username': [u'This field is required.']}", '<bound method SignupForm.non_field_errors of <myblog.forms.SignupForm object at 0x10c4979d0>>')
```

views.py

```
def signup(request): 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =  SignupForm(request.POST)
        raise Exception(form.is_valid(), repr(form.errors), repr(form.non_field_errors))
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
```

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    username= forms.CharField()
```

signup.html

```
<div id="signup-form">
    <form action="" method="post">
        {{ form.username }}
        <input class="post-button postcomment-button" type="submit" value="Get Started">
        {% csrf_token %}  
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you verify the data sent from the browser actually contains the username? You can check in the network tab of your browser's development tools

Comment: Also, you need to call `non_field_errors()` to actually get those errors

Answer (score 0):

I'm still pretty new to python, so may be compeletely wrong here, but raise Exception("something") ALWAYS throws an exception. It's a manual raise.

Comment out that line and just do if form.is_valid():

Comment: The exception was intentionally added to see the form errors as OP has posted.